# If all action profiles in a payoff matrix are Pareto optimal does this automatically mean that the game is a constant-sum?

Tags: game-theory

My guess is no, because constant sum means that the payoff is constant in every action profile, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Hint: try to draw the payoffs of some game and the Pareto optimal front. What does it mean that all payoffs are on that front?

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new to this, but what do you mean with front?

Comment: In the payoff space, where are the Pareto Optimal payoffs are?

Answer (score 0):

Having all the action profiles in a payoff matrix Pareto optimal does not imply that the game is constant sum. A counter example is given by

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
& L & M & R \\ 
\hline
H & (3, 4) & (4, 3) & (5, 2) \\ \hline
T & (6, 0) & (2, 5) & (1, 6) \\ \hline
\end{array}

As we can see they are all Pareto optimal. This game is not constant sum though because of $(T, L)$.